# Matrix Libraries vs For Loops in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, for-loop

Could you tell me if using a matrix library results in a faster run-time than regular for-loops? Currently, I have some methods that use for-loops that iterate through multidimensional vectors to calculate matrix products and element-wise products, where the matrix size is roughly 1000 columns by 400 rows. This method is the most called method in my program and I would like to know if using a matrix library would increase the program's speed. Also, which library would you recommend (from http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Benchmark, Eigen seems best to me)?

Thank You

Comment: why don't you benchamrk both and report the results here?

Comment: Here's a question: is this function call actually *causing* a bottleneck in your application? If not, why bother investing time to optimize it?

Comment: Try boost uBLAS: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm

Comment: @Demian: it doesn't take a lot of 1000x400 matrix products to make a difference performance-wise. The whole "don't optimize prematurely" thing is *generally* good advice, but sometimes it really just sounds like a broken record.

Comment: @jalf I think it sounds like a broken record because questions are asked prior profiling *a lot* on SO ;) By the wording of the question, I assumed that profiling hadn't already been done to locate specific bottlenecks. Perhaps I'm wrong, but that was my assumption and, hence, why the question was asked.

Comment: @jalf, @mitch, @demian, sorry for the long delay in my response. I ended up using the Eigen matrix library which noticably decreased the runtime of my progam. I did do profiling (using the Visual C++ Profiler and AMD CodeAnalyst) before asking this question and it reported  zzz_AsmCodeRange_begin (I googled this but I still have no idea what it means) as doing the most individual work, followed by one of my methods (which is the one I eventually optimized using matrices). Thank You for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes -- a fair number of C++ matrix libraries (E.g., MTL, uBLAS, Blitz++) use template metaprogramming to optimize their behavior. Absent a reason to do otherwise, I'd start with [Boost uBlas](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm). You might also want to look at the [OO numerics](http://www.oonumerics.org/oon/) libraries list for other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to answer the question "should I" instead of "which one" because it isn't clear that you actually *need* such a library.

Would a matrix library improve execution time? Probably.  The methods they teach you in high school are certainly not the fastest. However there are other issues to consider.

First, are you optimizing prematurely? Trying to make your program as fast as possible as soon as possible is tempting, but not always the right thing to do.  You have to make the determination if doing so is really a valid way to spend your time.

Second, will speed have any significant effect on usability? Making a program work in 2 seconds instead of 4 seconds isn't really worth the effort.... but 30 hours instead of 60 hours? Maybe so. I like to put emphasis on getting everything working before doing the polishing.

Finally, I have met several examples of code somebody else wrote several years before which was utterly useless.  Old libraries that couldn't be found or compiled with a new OS or compiler or something different meant that I had to completely rewrite something wasting weeks of my time.  It may have seemed like a good idea originally to get that extra few percent performance, but it meant that their code had a limited life span, especially because of poor documentation.

Keep It Simple Stupid is an excellent mantra for so many things. I am a strong advocate for only using libraries when absolutely necessary, and then only using those which seem to be long lived and stable.